# ASP.Net Web API Request URI Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, network-programming, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net Web API that generally works fine.  I have a Winforms client application that does GET requests.  The client application runs on our corporate network (the API is hosted as an Azure Website).  Occasionally, and inconsistently, the HttpClient calls I make add what seem to be corporate URLs in front of my GET call.

Example: I try to call send an HttpClient request to the following URL:     'http://xyzxyz.azurewebsites.net/api/user/1'

but the actual request made is:

```
'http://usgaabc1iru01/B0000D0000N0001F0000S0000R0004/http://xyzxyz.azurewebsites.net/api/user/1'
```

This obviously causes an error.

I've asked our IT department what may be happening and they are at a loss.  Hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Edit:

Here's the code I use.  First I have a static method I call everything I make a call to the API to get the HttpClient (is this awkward/bad perhaps):

```
public static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {

                var credentials = new NetworkCredential(GlobalVariables.CurrentUser.UserName, GlobalVariables.CurrentUser.Password);
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                handler.Credentials = credentials;

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(PublicClasses.GlobalVariables.BaseUriString);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                GlobalVariables.CredentialedHttpClient = client;
            }
            return GlobalVariables.CredentialedHttpClient;
        }
   }
```

Here's a simple GET call I use:

```
public static List<Project> GetAllProjects()
    {
        try
        {

            HttpClient client = GetHttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/project").Result;  // Blocking call!
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var projects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Project>>().Result;
                return (List<Project>)projects; 
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                return null;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for why is this happening but I came across similar issue in a web form (not a win forms client). That is solved by using base meta tag.I am not sure if that solves your problem, but you can give a try.

You can use base address with HttpClient like this (if you are not already doing this):

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xyzxyz.azurewebsites.net/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/user/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //add your code
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is similar but slightly different.  For one thing, I'm not putting everything in a 'using' block.  I also don't run "clear" to the defaultrequestheaders -- take a look at my edited Question and let me know if you think your code may render different results than mine.